# $S^2-D$ being equidecomposable with $S^2$ and its details

Tags: geometry, group-theory, set-theory

In the Wikipedia proof of Banach-Tarski paradox (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach-Tarski_paradox#Some_details.2C_fleshed_out), there is a stuff about $S^2-D$ being equidecomposable with $S^2$ as the following:

> In Step 3, we partitioned the sphere into orbits of our group $H$. To
>   streamline the proof, we omitted the discussion of points that are
>   fixed by some rotation; since the paradoxical decomposition of $F_2$
>   relies on shifting certain subsets, the fact that some points are
>   fixed might cause some trouble. Since any rotation of $S^2$ (other
>   than the null rotation) has exactly two fixed points, and since $H$,
>   which is isomorphic to $F_2$, is countable, there are countably many
>   points of $S^2$ that are fixed by some rotation in $H$, denote this
>   set of fixed points $D$. Step 3 proves that $S^2 − D$ admits a
>   paradoxical decomposition.

and

> Claim: $S^2 − D$ is equidecomposable with $S^2$.
>
> Proof.  Let $λ$ be some line through the origin that does not
>   intersect any point in $D$ – this is possible since $D$ is countable.
>   Let $J$ be the set of angles, $α$, such that for some natural number
>   $n$, and some $P$ in $D$, $r(nα)P$ is also in $D$, where $r(nα)$ is a
>   rotation about $λ$ of $nα$. Then $J$ is countable so there exists an
>   angle $θ$ not in $J$. Let $ρ$ be the rotation about $λ$ by $θ$, then
>   $ρ$ acts on $S^2$ with no fixed points in $D$, i.e., $ρ^n(D)$ is
>   disjoint from $D$, and for natural $m<n$, $ρ^n(D)$ is disjoint from
>   $ρ^m(D)$. Let $E$ be the disjoint union of $ρ^n(D)$ over $n = 0, 1, 2, ....$ Then $S^2 = E ∪ (S^2 − E)$ ~ $ρ(E) ∪ (S^2 − E) = (E − D) ∪ (S^2 − E) = S^2 − D$, where ~ denotes "is equidecomposable to".

I am having a hard time understanding $S^2 = E ∪ (S^2 − E)$ ~ $ρ(E) ∪ (S^2 − E)$. Why is this true?

> The proof sketched above requires 2×4×2 + 8 = 24
>   pieces, a factor of 2 to remove fixed points, a factor 4 from step 1,
>   a factor 2 to recreate fixed points, and 8 for the center point of the
>   second ball.

Can anyone explain this? OK, I do get that there are two fixed points for each axis that rotaton gets based on - but that gives me nothing about above.

Comment: Can anyone comment?

Comment: See the comments at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126168/

Comment: You should really stop cross-posting between the two sites like that. The communities have a very large intersection, and it makes it more difficult to track possible comments, edits and so on. Ask on one site, and if after a week you haven't got any comments or reasonable answers ask on the second site. When you do, always make a note of it on both posts (comment the old, and on the top of the new). This way you avoid annoying people.